# Read block of characters from file at a time and next block in next cycle in C

Tags: c++, c, file-io, fread

Suppose I have 100 characters in a **file**. I want to read 10 character at a time, work with that and next I want to read 11th-20th = 10 characters and work with them and so on.

Now how can I read this block of data using C? Also say if there are only 5 charactes left then it shouldn't go into an error, rather give me a count of how much characters read this time.

All the methods found over net suggest me to read all character at once or read character one by one. I saw

```
char but[20];
fread(buf, 1,10, fp);
```

This looked promising. But I'm unable to use it for my purpose. After reading the 1st to 10th character how can I instruct to bring 11th to 20th character?

C solutions are required but C++ solutions can be used as well.

Comment: So... a C++ solution using std::string and iostreams will be fine (in other words, you are comfortable "translating" it or switching to use C++ instead?)

Comment: @crashmstr I want a C solution, but if there isn't any other way to do it or no other better way then I can accept C++ solutions and try them to use in my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fread()` is a sequential file operation. You just keep calling it until EOF or `itemsread == 0`.

```
do {
    itemsread = fread (buffer, sizeof(char), 10, fp);
    for (i=0; i<itemsread; i++)
        { ... }
} while (itemsread);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to process 10 bytes at a time, until you reach EOF?
The C library function `int fgetc(FILE *stream)` gets the next character (an unsigned char) from the specified stream and advances the position indicator for the stream. So we can try to read 10 bytes into the buffer, if EOF is encountered, we process the `n` bytes in the buffer.
Maybe something like this:

```
    int main ()
    {
        FILE *fp;
        char block[10] = {0};
        int c;
        int n = 0; //counter

        fp = fopen("file.txt","r");
        if(fp == NULL) return -1;

        while (c=fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
        {
            block[n] = (char)c;
            ++n;
            while(n < 10 && c=fgetc(fp)!=EOF){
                block[n] = char(c);
                ++n;
            }
            //read 10 chars or end of file find out
            if(c==EOF) {
                //you've read n bytes, do something with those n bytes and,
                break;
            }
            else {
                //do something with your 10 bytes and
                n = 0; // reset n
                continue; //not necessary
            }
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
```